# is a Python dictionary thread-safe when keys are thread IDs?

Tags: python, multithreading, dictionary, critical-section

Is a Python dictionary thread safe when using the thread ID of the current thread only to read or write? Like

```
import thread
import threading

class Thread(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, data):
        super(Thread, self).__init__()
        self.data = data

    def run(self):
        data = self.data[thread.get_ident()]
        # ...
```

Comment: I'd think not.  Keys can still collide, and data can still move around in memory during an expansion of the underlying datastructure, whether or not your threads are careful not to use the same keys.

Comment: Actually, looking at your code, if it's truly representative of your problem, it's not clear to me why you need to do this at all.  Are you trying to use `data` as a sort of signalling pipe between the master and workers?  I don't see why you can't just pass the individual element of the `data` dict to the thread `__init__` and use that as `self.data` instead of indexing in to it with the thread's id.  Where are you populating data at that id in the first place?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**If** `data` is a standard Python dictionary, the `__getitem__` call is implemented entirely in C, as is the `__hash__` method on the integer value returned by `thread.get_ident()`. At that point the `data.__getitem__(<thread identifier>)` call is thread safe. The same applies to writing to `data`; the `data.__setitem__()` call is entirely handled in C.

The moment any of these hooks are implemented in Python code, the GIL can be released between bytecodes and all bets are off.

This all makes the assumption you are using CPython; Jython, IronPython, PyPy and other python implementations may make different decisions on when to switch threads.

You'd be better of using the [`threading.local()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#threading.local) mapping object *instead*, as that is guaranteed to provide you with a thread-local namespace. It only supports attribute access though.