# Are dict thread-safe with pypy?

Tags: python, pypy

In CPython, it seems that built-in operations are atomic and Thread safe, according to: https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-global-interpreter-lock.

> This simplifies the CPython implementation by making the object model (including critical built-in types such as dict) implicitly safe against concurrent access.

However I couldn't find any information for Pypy: https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/cpython_differences.html.

Other [stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23157243/4172685) point that PyPy behavior **may** be different but it's not clear if it actually is.

> This all makes the assumption you are using CPython; Jython, IronPython, Pypy and other python implementations may make different decisions on when to switch threads.

Are Pypy dict (and other built-in) thread safe ? Or not ?

Comment: Define thread safe when you're talking about dicts, changing values between threads will cause issues for instance :)

Comment: @Torxed, I'm using thread safe in the same meaning as the CPython description I copied. By thread-safe, I'm asking if built-in mutations are atomics ? Ex: Does inserting two different keys from two different threads always succeed ?

Comment: "cpython_differences.html" is supposed to list all known differences in behavior---thread-safety is not mentioned because you're supposed to get the same multithread behavior as CPython.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this question in the FAQ](https://doc.pypy.org/en/latest/faq.html#does-pypy-have-a-gil-why), PyPy does have a GIL. This should prevent any concurrent access to any type of variable; as only one thread can actually be doing anything at a time.

> Yes, PyPy has a GIL. Removing the GIL is very hard.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I wish it the documentation was more explicit about the thread behavior, but I guess it is safe to assume behavior is the same as CPython.

Comment: Not a problem, the link I shared does strongly hint/mention the main reason for the GIL is to protect mutable data types across threads.